# Wrong elements in the array for other processors after broadcasting (MPI)

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to broadcast the pointer to `x` to the other processors.  It's declared as a global variable along with `err` and `num`.  But after broadcasting, the contents of the array are incorrect for all processors except `rank 0` while `err` and `num` are read correctly.

I've added comments in caps to point out what I'm referring to in the above.  The bottom print loop gives the correct values of `err` and `num` after broadcasting regardless of rank but the contents of `x` is only correct if the rank is `0`.  Anyone know why?

Note:  I'm not that familiar with C but the elements of the array seem to have been populated correctly as process 0 is able to access the array and read the correct elements from it.

Sample input...

```
3 
5.05
2 3 4
```

Output if I set rank to 0...

```
3
0.010000
0 2.000000
1 3.000000
2 4.000000
```

Output if I set rank to 1...

```
3
0.010000
0 1209010463764815312582472227618816.000000
1 18988728894356880079764586496.000000
2 78657026497739634549916490384015360.000000
```

and code..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>


float err; 
float *x;  // DECLARING X HERE
int num;

void get_input();  


void get_input(FILE* fp, int process_rank, int comm_size)
{
    if(process_rank == 0)
    {
        x = (float *)malloc(num * sizeof(float));

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%f", &x[i]);
        }

        // BROADCASTING X
        MPI_Bcast(&x, num, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        fclose(fp);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }    
    fscanf(fp, "%d ", &num);
    fscanf(fp, "%f ", &err);

    int comm_size;
    int process_rank;
    x = (float *)malloc(num * sizeof(float));  /* The unknowns */

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process_rank);

    MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&err, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    get_input(fp, process_rank, comm_size);

    // CHECKING X
    if(process_rank == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", num);
        printf("%f\n", err);
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%d %f\n", i, x[i]);
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It could be an issue with not understanding C fully as well but I thought if the variables were declared before the processors were created that they have their own copy of it?  I thought that was the case for MPI but maybe I wrote things incorrectly in my notes

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not casting?  For example it's done here the same as I've seen in other sites...
http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/3300/spr16/Notes/C/Array/heap.html

Comment: I have not seen any other way of declaring an array on the heap so figured it was the correct way.  I'm definitely not an expert at C but have to use C.  As for debugging, the print statements are what I'm using for that which in this case is the very bottom where I check for process rank number.  When it's 0, the elements of x are correct.  When it's any other rank, the values are very large numbers.

Comment: :) "Allocating an array in C (optional)" - the website mentions this and shows the same syntax.  That's what I was referring to sorry.  It's also the same syntax that the professor used in his skeleton script

Comment: Your question is really about MPI, so you do not need the `C` tag. Some folks have a strong opinion about whether `malloc()` result should be casted or not, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc lists pros and cons.

Comment: Ok thanks!  I'll read later on what you guys were referring to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `MPI_Bcast()` is a pointer to a buffer, and not the address of a pointer to a buffer.

So you need to replace `MPI_Bcast(&x, ...);` with `MPI_Bcast(x, ...);`

You also need to allocate `x` and `MPI_Bcast()` on **all** ranks.
Here is the corrected `get_input()` function

```
void get_input(FILE* fp, int process_rank, int comm_size)
{
    x = (float *)malloc(num * sizeof(float));

    if(process_rank == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%f", &x[i]);
        }
    }

    // BROADCASTING X
    MPI_Bcast(x, num, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

That being said, you might want to revamp your code so only rank `0` open/read/close the input file.

Comment: I thought that might be an issue but I get the same output still :( I'll post the results

Comment: Maybe the way I'm allocating `x`?  I'm checking

Comment: @pad11 I overlooked an other issue, and I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks!  I just caught that too.  Thank you!  I thought the allocation on rank 0 and then broadcasting would be enough but yeah that was wrong.

Comment: And yeah, I will change get_input to be only done by process 0 as well

Comment: `MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation, which means it has to be called by **all** the tasks of the communicator.